# I am running a nextjs project in vscode. when I do npm run dev its ok in terminal but in browser localhost refused to connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server, localhost

when I do
npm run dev in my terminal to run a nextjs project,
gives output > client@1.0.0 dev > next dev ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
but in browser it shows This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I had a previous next project that was running in localhost://3000 but I deleted that project.

I tried some solve from google but not working

Comment: which OS you are suing ?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to network proxy in the setting and disable it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem but it was for an angular open source project. If your project has an environment.ts file change these lines to look like this:

production : false,
useEmulators: false,

This should solve your problem

Comment: Your answer seems to refer to a different tech stack to the OP

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34584068)